# How to schedule a real-time task with absolute start time?

Tags: pthreads, real-time, linux-rt

For a TSN-aware communication protocol stack and framework, I need to be able to execute real-time threads not only running at very exact intervals, but starting at precise timeslots deducted from ptpd.

Currently, I did that by delaying / yielding the task until the start time. For a PoC of my TSN communication this was sufficient, but with the Linux real-time extensions, there must be a better / more effective way. The jitter introduced was about 800us between two Beaglebones (running Linux 4.14.71-ti-r80 #1 SMP PREEMPT).

Using a cyclic pthread, I synchronised the start of my network producer task (Note: vos_ prefix denotes my OS abstraction methods, actually matching POSIX calls):

```
for (;; )
{
    /* Synchronize with starttime */
    vos_getTime(&now);                      /* get initial time */
    vos_subTime(&now, &startTime);

    /* Wait for multiples of interval */

    execTime = ((UINT32)now.tv_usec % interval);
    waitingTime = interval - execTime;
    if (waitingTime >= interval)
    {
        ...error checks omitted
    }

    /* Idle for the difference */
    vos_threadDelay(waitingTime); /* pthread_testcancel() inside */

    vos_getTime(&priorCall);  /* get initial time */
    pFunction(pArguments);    /* thread function: send data */
    vos_getTime(&afterCall);  /* get time after function has returned */

    /* get the runtime of pFunction() */
    vos_subTime(&afterCall, &priorCall);

    /* afterCall holds now the time difference... */
    if (afterCall.tv_sec <= MAXSEC_FOR_USECPRESENTATION)
    {
        ...runtime / error handling omitted
    }
}
```

The above code produces a jitter of about 800us at interval times of 5ms (using Linux 4.14 without RT-extension and policy Round-Robin), which is fairly good - but ineffective when it comes to multiple threads all doing scheduled traffic...

With Linux 4.1.15-ti-rt-r43 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT, I'm planning to use SCHED_DEADLINE as policy, but struct sched_attr provides no start-time-parameter. The runtime-checking in the above code is not needed, then. But:

How can I effectively use Linux's real-time extensions to have a thread running at exact absolute times, say for example at every 1ms starting at absolute real time 'now' + 0.0075s (e.g. now.0085, now.0095, now.0105 ...), without the overhead of the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clock_nanosleep()` POSIX function has an absolute deadline mode:

```
#define NSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000
/* Initial delay, 7.5ms */
const long start_delay_ns = 7500000;
/* Cycle time, 1ms */
const long cycle_time_ns = 1000000;
struct timespec deadline;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &deadline);
deadline.tv_nsec += start_delay_ns;
deadline.tv_sec += deadline.tv_nsec / NSEC_PER_SEC;
deadline.tv_nsec %= NSEC_PER_SEC;

for (;;)
{
    struct timespec now;

    /* Sleep until deadline */
    while (clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL) != 0)
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return; /* error handling here */

    pFunction(pArguments);    /* thread function: send data */

    /* Calculate next deadline */
    deadline.tv_nsec += cycle_time_ns;
    deadline.tv_sec += deadline.tv_nsec / NSEC_PER_SEC;
    deadline.tv_nsec %= NSEC_PER_SEC;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    if (now.tv_sec > deadline.tv_sec || (now.tv_sec == deadline.tv_sec && deadline.tv_nsec > now.tv_nsec))
        return; /* time overrun error handling here */
}
```

Comment: Thanx, caf. For TSN, I need CLOCK_REALTIME, because it is adjusted by the PTP daemon. In my code, vos_threadDelay uses clock_nanosleep() as well.

Comment: @Bernd: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is adjusted by clock rate adjustments too, though it isn't affected by clock jumps.  Your `vos_threadDelay` is using a relative timeout with the clock, whereas sleeping until a deadline is more accurately done by using an absolute timeout (requested with the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag).